# How to create Private directory like private classes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider the below folder structure. I want to restrict the access to `_child` directory, like only the parnet of `_child`  should have access to it. `another_parnent` or another directory should not access it.

```
_ another_parnet
- parent/
  - parnet1.dart
  - parent2.dart
  - parent3.dart
  - _child/
    - child1.dart
    - child2.dart
    - child3.dart
```

Is it possible to do in Flutter?

Tried googling and going through flutter documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. The only privacy you can achieve is within files and classes using the `_` notation.

By using the `part` keyword in the "child files" you could have a folder structure between the `parent` and `child` directories as you've written it with all classes in the children marked with `_` and thereby only allowing parent to use them. I.e. not allowing `another_parent` to use them. It would essentially be like having it all in one file. But in this scenario you need to have one top parent file that all subdirectory files (and other parent files in your example) are a part of.